# How to add \ before all special characters in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add '\' before all special characters in a string in MATLAB, could anyone please help me out. Here is the example:

```
tStr = 'Hi, I'm a Big (Not So Big) MATLAB addict; Since my school days!';
```

I want this string to be changed to:

```
'Hi\, I\'m a Big \(Not so Big \) MATLAB addict\; Since my school days\!'
```

Comment: Define "special characters". You seem to be treating ',' as one but not '!'

Answer (score 12):

The escape character in Matlab is the single quote ('), not the backslash (\), like in C language. Thus, your string must be like this:

```
tStr = 'Hi\, I\''m a Big (Not so Big ) MATLAB addict\; Since my school days!'
```

Answer (score 5):

I took the list of special charecters defined on the Mathworks webpage to do this:

```
special = '[]{}()=''.().....,;:%%{%}!@';

tStr = 'Hi, I''m a Big (Not So Big) MATLAB addict; Since my school days!';

outStr = '';
for l = tStr
    if (length(find(special == l)) > 0)
        outStr = [outStr, '\', l];
    else
        outStr = [outStr, l];
    end
end
```

which will automatically add those \s. You do need to use two single quotes ('') in place of the apostrophe in your input string. If tStr is obtained with the function input(), or something similar, this will procedure will still work.

Edited:

Or using regular expressions:

```
regexprep(tStr,'([[\]{}()=''.(),;:%%{%}!@])','\\$1')
```

Comment: This is helpful Molly. Thanks for your response. I was wondering this could be done easily using regexprep.

Comment: That should be `..., '\\$1');`, otherwise you're escaping the dollar sign.

Comment: answer can replaced with the regexprep oneliner.

Comment: I could only get the regex to work with an extra slash: 
`regexprep(tStr,'([[\\]{}()=''.(),;:%%{%}!@])','\\$1')`